# How do i manipulate a string/dataitem in my Listview?

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview, eval

This is how i am showing the string in listview:

```
<%# Eval("Description")%>
```

This is the code in a method to get the data for listview :

```
lstBlog.DataSource = blg;

        lstBlog.DataBind();
```

How can i manipulate the "Description" string ... i.e. get only first 50 characters/stripping off any html tags from the string .......

Thanx in advance

Comment: i tried to use substring to shorten the string length but in my list view it worked only for the first data row.... and an clear explanation for stripping the html tags from the string would help me a lot... again thanx

Answer (score 0):

in aspx page

```
<%# CutString(Eval("Description").ToString(),50) %>
```

in cs

```
public string CutString(string value , int len)
{
       // ....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In aspx page, you can directly take string part as below:

```
<%# Convert.ToString(Eval("Description")).Substring(0, 50) %>
```

"OR"

In aspx page and create ItemDataBound event for the ListView

```
<asp:Label ID="lblDescription" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
```

In code behind, create ItemDataBound

```
protected void lvData_ItemDataBound(object sender, ListViewItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListViewItemType.DataItem)
    {
        Blog blg = (Blog)e.Item.DataItem;
        Label lblDescription = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("lblDescription");
        lblDescription.Text = blg.Description.Substring(0, 50);
    }
}
```

To strip HTML tags please see here: http://www.dotnetperls.com/remove-html-tags

Comment: i used this technique but my list view only produces the "description" field for the first row.... after that it doesn't work

Comment: Could you please try with the "OR" section, thanks for your time.

Comment: thanx for the reply ...... i will tell u whether it worked or not as soon as i test the code......again thank u very much